# WPF DataGrid cell background using binding

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, colors, background

I have a DataGrid with column named Color.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding MyColor.Percentage}"/>
```

The ItemSource of DataGrid is some object with `MyColor` property inside.

```
public class MyColor
{
    Color Background { get; set; }
    int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

When ItemSource is set column auto-fills with values of `Percentage`. Now I'd like to set background of each cell in this column to color corresponding to `MyColor.Color` property. Is there a way to do it using binding? Something like

```
Background="{Binding MyColor.Color}"
```

`Color` property is in html format #XXXXXXXX (is it called html format?).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set it via `CellStyle`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Color" Binding="{Binding MyColor.Percentage}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyColor.Background}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Also you have to change your `MyColor` class to have a `Background` property with type `Brush`, not `Color`. Or you can use a converter to convert `Color` into `SolidColorBrush`.

Comment: Ok, I managed convert input to SolidColorBrush, but there is a problem. I assign ItemSource to DataGrid using Dispatcher because of the rest of my application and when I added your XAML code to mine, it pops out error "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as DependencyObject"